# Custom form not showing input fields

Tags: list, custom-form, sharepoint-hosted-app, aspx

I have created custom newform aspx page binded to newform fromschema as

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="Import.aspx" Path="Import.aspx"  WebPartZoneID="Main" Template="Import.aspx"/>
```

Added fiels on new aspx page as

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">


    <div>
        <SharePoint:FieldLabel runat="server" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="New" />
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="New" />
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="New" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

also made page deployement type as ElementFile but on page it only shows filed label but not showing input fields as 
[image]

Suggest some help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> `FieldName` is the corresponding column name in the list. Do not used
>   display name. Using **Display name** also works but when you change
>   **display name** the **control won’t render**. So I always recommend using columns name for `FieldName`.

Kindly check **Note** under the **step 4** in below article.

[SharePoint List NewForm Customization in SharePoint Hosted App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wilsonreddygajarla/2014/12/13/sharepoint-list-newform-customization-in-sharepoint-hosted-app/)

Comment: I have use internal name not display name. also followed all the steps mention in the above link but not working

Comment: So silly to ask you but Have you mapped form correctly as mentioned in **step 6** as i think it is showing your custom form inplace of **DisplayForm** so it wont show yo controls? Kindly check it & let me know.

Comment: yes I have done that also

Comment: Can you please cross-check using IE DOM that if the controls are on the page or not?

Comment: Did you find any resolution?

Comment: No I haven't found any solution